# ejs complains of undefined variable in rendering a template

Tags: node.js

The code shown immediately below runs the template file beneath through ejs.  It is intended that <%= query.animal %> be evaluated.  Instead, I'm getting the complaint that "query is not defined."  Can anyone help me with why that is?  Thanks.

... doug

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require("fs");
var ejs = require("ejs");
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var query = require('url').parse(request.url,true).query;
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.end(ejs.render(fs.readFileSync('infile.html','utf8')));
});
server.listen(8000,'208.43.220.79');
console.log("Server running at http://208.43.220.79:8000/");
```

Here's the file:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head><title>Test 2</title></head>
 <body>
  <h2>My <%= query.animal %> has fleas.</h2>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly pass variables to your templates:

```
response.end(ejs.render(fs.readFileSync('infile.html','utf8'), { query: query }));
```

Comment: That does it.  Thanks.

Comment: I was reviewing your most-helpful answer.  I sure would like to know how you knew that.  I'm thinking that on occassion there may be additional variables that I would like to pass as well.  Whilie I definitely have some ideas as to how that would be done, I'd really like to read to relevant documentation.  Who knows what else I might learn?  Anyway, do you have a URL that you could point me to?  Thanks.